# Android Socket Connection in Threads

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to listen to read short messages ( 4-10 char long) via a Socket connection. My App is successfully connection to the server but the connection doesn't seem to be held. I never see a message which the server has send :-/

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Socket socket;

Handler updateConversationHandler;

Thread serverThread = null;

private TextView text;

public static final int SERVERPORT = 1111;
Thread commThread;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    /*
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

   */

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.commThread = new Thread(new CommunicationThread());
    this.commThread.start();


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Snackbar.make(view, "Communication should be openend", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;


    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            try {
                socket = new Socket("10.0.1.1", 1111);
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                String read = input.readLine();

                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      Log.v("Blub", msg);
      // here should be some Work on the UI ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, I would try logging the String "read" to see if it even gets that far.

Comment: How are you sending the data? _readLine()_ will wait for a line terminator before returning. Keep in mind it returns _null_ at end of stream.

Comment: osw.write("Open", 0, 4);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close(); 

I'm writing this data from APP --> Server ( Server reacts) and send that in the same manner to my client

Comment: Try changing it to "osw.write("Open\n", 0, 5);" \n is Line Feed.

Comment: That's it ... :), now my app is recognizing the commands. THANK YOU!